# trying to get the single exp payment

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT member_Id ,
       PERIOD_DIFF(
           DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m'), 
           DATE_FORMAT(memberToMship_StartDate,'%Y%m')
        )  + 
        (
           DAY(memberToMship_StartDate) < memberToMship_DueDay
        ) + 
        (
           DAY(now()) > memberToMship_DueDay
        ) - 1  
        AS ExpPayments 
FROM membertomships
```

it was giving all exp payments for all members that was fine, can i get the single exp payment for single member.....

Do i need add any join or any where condition ..

Comment: Something like `WHERE member_Id = 5` or `WHERE member_name = 'George'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add [where](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause in the end of the query

```
where  member_Id = {enter the id}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the `member_Id` you could just add a `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT member_Id ,
       PERIOD_DIFF(
           DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m'), 
           DATE_FORMAT(memberToMship_StartDate,'%Y%m')
        )  + 
        (
           DAY(memberToMship_StartDate) < memberToMship_DueDay
        ) + 
        (
           DAY(now()) > memberToMship_DueDay
        ) - 1  
        AS ExpPayments 
FROM membertomships
WHERE member_Id = 213
```

Comment: +1 For straightforward solution and really readable formatting.